# How do I make a scrollview grow and scroll up?

Tags: android, xml, scrollview, android-linearlayout, gravity

My problem is that I add new messages to the LinearLayout, and the ScrollView has the property of "leaving" up every time. Or, for example, an open keyboard causes the scroll to sink under it. I tried using layout_gravity bottom, which gave me the desired result, but the scroll does not work. Essentially my question is how from layout_gravity bottom to allow scroll up. Here's my xml:

```
<ScrollView
android:id="@+id/messscroll"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"

app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/relativeLayout"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout2">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/messagebox"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="false"

    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:divider="@drawable/separator"
    android:dividerPadding="3dp"

    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="1px"
    android:showDividers="middle"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

For keyboard-related issues interfering with your ScrollView, you can use `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustPan"` in your activity's Manifest entry, e.g.

```
<activity
    android:name=".activities.LoginActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustPan" />
```

Comment: I mean its works but i have an empty place when i'm typing

Comment: a little more description in your post along with a possible screenshot might help others help you!